# How can I show an error message if a value already exists in the database?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have a page where users can create topics via ajax. Before a topic is created I check to see if it already exists in the database. If the topic exists in the database then I want to show an error message via a div box before proceeding to submit the new topic. Everything works fine. But I can't figure out how to make the error message appear only when the topic already exists in the database.

Here is the page with my form and ajax code:

```
<script>
    function cancelTopicCreation() {
        $(".create-topic-cancel-button, .close_blue_modal").click(function () {
            $('#id-create-topic-picture-preview').attr('src','<?php echo BASE_URL; ?>content/pictures/layout/default_group_icon.png');
        });
    }

    function close_blue_modal() {
        $('#blue_modal_mask').fadeOut(144);
        $('.blue_modal_window').fadeOut(144);
        $('.blue_modal_window_two').fadeOut(144);
        $('.blue_modal_window_three').fadeOut(144);
        $('.blue_modal_window_five').fadeOut(144);
    }
    function createTopic() {
        /*----------------submit title of new topic----------------*/
        $(document).ready(function() {
            var topicTitle = $(".create-topic-input-box").val();/* get the value of the topic title input and put it in a variable */
            var dataString = 'topicTitle='+ topicTitle;/* returns successful data submission message when the entered information is stored in database. */
            if(topicTitle == '') {/* if there is no title entered then */
                alert("Please Fill All Fields");
            } else {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: site_url+'resources/create-topic.php',
                    data: dataString,
                    cache: false,
                    success: function(result) {/* if the ajax submit is successful then */
                        $('#createTopicForm').each(function() {
                            this.reset();
                        });
                        close_blue_modal();
                        $('#id-create-topic-picture-preview').attr('src','<?php echo BASE_URL; ?>content/pictures/layout/default_group_icon.png');
                        $("#results").html(''); //append data into #results element
                        load_contents(track_page); //initial content load
                    }
                });
            }
            return false;
        });
        /*----------------upload topic picture----------------*/
        $(document).ready(function() {
             var input = document.getElementById("id-create-topic-picture-input");
              file = input.files[0];
              if (file != undefined){
                formData= new FormData();
                if(!!file.type.match(/image.*/)){
                  formData.append("nameTopicPicture", file);
                  $.ajax({
                    url: site_url+'resources/upload-topic-icon.php',
                    type: "POST",
                    data: formData,
                    processData: false,
                    contentType: false,
                    success: function(data) {/* you can do something if the picture upload is successful here */}
                  });
                } else {
                  alert('Not a valid image!');
                }
              } else{/* if there is no image selected then */}
        });
    }    
</script>
<div id="blue_modal_mask" class="close_blue_modal"></div><!--#blue_modal_mask .close_blue_modal-->
<div id="blue_modal_four" class="blue_modal_window_two">
    <div onclick="return cancelTopicCreation();" class="close_blue_modal icon-x-mark"></div><!--.close_white_modal-->
    <div class="create-topic-label">Create topic</div><!--.create-topic-label-->
    <div class="create-topic-error-message">That topic already exists. Please choose a different topic name.</div><!--.create-topic-label-->
    <div class="create-topic-description"><div class="icon-book create-topic-description-icon"></div>Topics are used to organize content on the website.</div><!--.create-topic-label-->
    <form id="createTopicForm" action="<?php echo BASE_URL?>resources/upload_topic_icon.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <div class="create-topic-input-wrap">
            <label for='id-create-topic-input-box'><div class='create-topic-name-label'>Topic name</div></label>
            <input class="create-topic-input-box" id="id-create-topic-input-box" type="text" name="topicTitle" placeholder="Enter a topic name" autocomplete="off"><!--input.index_sign_up_input-->
            <div class="create-topic-autocomplete-result-box">
                <div class="create-topic-autocomplete-result-list nice-scroll">
                    <div class="create-topic-autocomplete-result-item">
                        <img class="create-topic-autocomplete-result-item-picture" src="content/pictures/layout/default_group_icon.png" alt="">
                        <div class="create-topic-autocomplete-result-item-content">
                            <div class="create-topic-autocomplete-result-item-title">The title of the result goes here</div>
                            <div class="create-topic-autocomplete-result-item-details">The details of the result goes here</div>
                        </div><!--create-topic-autocomplete-result-item-content-->
                    </div><!--create-topic-autocomplete-result-item-->
                    <div class="create-topic-autocomplete-result-item">
                        <img class="create-topic-autocomplete-result-item-picture" src="content/pictures/layout/default_group_icon.png" alt="">
                        <div class="create-topic-autocomplete-result-item-content">
                            <div class="create-topic-autocomplete-result-item-title">The name of the result goes here</div>
                            <div class="create-topic-autocomplete-result-item-details">The details of the result goes here</div>
                        </div><!--create-topic-autocomplete-result-item-content-->
                    </div><!--create-topic-autocomplete-result-item-->
                    <div class="create-topic-autocomplete-result-item">
                        <img class="create-topic-autocomplete-result-item-picture" src="content/pictures/layout/default_group_icon.png" alt="">
                        <div class="create-topic-autocomplete-result-item-content">
                            <div class="create-topic-autocomplete-result-item-title">The name of the result goes here</div>
                            <div class="create-topic-autocomplete-result-item-details">The details of the result goes here</div>
                        </div><!--create-topic-autocomplete-result-item-content-->
                    </div><!--create-topic-autocomplete-result-item-->
                    <div class="create-topic-autocomplete-result-item-empty">Nothing found</div>
                </div><!--create-topic-autocomplete-result-list-->
            </div><!--create-topic-autocomplete-result-box-->
        </div>
        <div class="create-topic-picture-preview-wrap">
            <img id="id-create-topic-picture-preview" src="<?php echo BASE_URL; ?>content/pictures/layout/default_group_icon.png" class="create-topic-picture-preview">
        </div>
        <div id="create-topic-footer">
            <label for="id-create-topic-picture-input" >
                <div class="icon-camera create-topic-camera-icon"></div>
            </label>
            <input name="nameTopicPicture" accept="image/*" type="file" class="create-topic-picture-input" id="id-create-topic-picture-input">
            <a onclick="return createTopic();" class="create-topic-button">Create</a>
            <a onclick="return cancelTopicCreation();" class="create-topic-cancel-button cancel_blue_modal">Cancel</a>
        </div><!--#new_post_options-->
    </form>
</div><!--.blue_modal_one .blue_modal_window-->
```

Here is my php page that is referenced by the ajax:

```
session_start();/* start new or resume existing session */
require_once('Wall.php');
$Wall = new Wall;/* create a new object for the class */
$languageFile = $Wall->getTheLanguageFileForFilesInTheResourcesFolder();/* get the language file and put it in a variable */ 
include_once ($languageFile);
$idOfLoggedInUser = isset($_SESSION['mem_id']) ? intval($_SESSION['mem_id']) : "";/* get the id of the logged in user and put it in a variable */
$topicTitle = $_POST['topicTitle'];/* get the entered topic title and put it in a variable */
$query = mysqli_query($databaseConnection, "SELECT columnTopicTitle FROM tableTopics WHERE columnTopicTitle='".$topicTitle."'");
if (mysqli_num_rows($query) != 0) {
    echo "Username already exists";
} else {
    $idOfLastTopicCreated = $Wall->createTopic($idOfLoggedInUser, $topicTitle);/* get the language file and put it in a variable */ 
    $_SESSION['idOfLastTopicCreated'] = $idOfLastTopicCreated;
}

    $advert = array(
        'ajax' => 'Hello world!',
        'advert' => $row['adverts'],
     );
    echo json_encode($advert);
?>
```

How can I tell javascript that a topic by that name already exists. If the topic already exists in the database then I want the ajax to stop and show the error popup div. Please help. I have tried to use json to pass a string that indicates that the topic already exists in the database. But was not successful. I have tried passing the string from php to query but the problem with that is that the string doesn't change on multiple attempts. And so it shows the error every time.

Comment: More of a comment here, you have your php echoing a text string `Username already exists` on error but you also have it also `echo` a `json_encode()` at the bottom. Your error message will mal-form the json. It would write `Username already exists{"ajax":"Hello world","advert":"whatever"}` which is invalid if it does error.

Comment: Okay I need to show a div with js if the username already exists. How can I do that? Should I use ajax to return  a variable or json? How should I do it?

Comment: @RomeoHennessy Use json only because you are looping a json in your jquery code.

Comment: The problem is that my jSON was returning undefined. I don't know how to use JSON correctly.

Comment: @RomeoHennessy Where are you storing the db data in `$row` ?? You have missed that.

Comment: @RomeoHennessy Use `$row = mysqli_query`. You have not initialized `$row`.

Comment: @Ayush: OP question is about how to display a message for the `if` part... And you focus on the `else` part. You may be right... But your out of the question scope.

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette He is using an ajax call. What is the point of using `alert` in the script. He needs to return the value to the ajax call and then process the value there `sucess` or `fail`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have your PHP to send a script instead of a simple string...

Something like this would also work:

```
$query = mysqli_query($databaseConnection, "SELECT columnTopicTitle FROM tableTopics WHERE columnTopicTitle='".$topicTitle."'");
if (mysqli_num_rows($query) != 0) {
    //echo "Username already exists";
    ?>
    <script>
    alert("Username already exists");
    </script>
    <?php
} else { ....
```

So you could have an hidden `div` in your main page, styled with CSS... Just to show any message in a much cuter way than an alert:

```
$query = mysqli_query($databaseConnection, "SELECT columnTopicTitle FROM tableTopics WHERE columnTopicTitle='".$topicTitle."'");
if (mysqli_num_rows($query) != 0) {
    //echo "Username already exists";
    ?>
    <script>
    $("#myHiddenDiv").html("Username already exists").fadeIn(600);
    </script>
    <?php
} else { ....
```

In your Ajax `success` callback :

```
success: function(result) {
    // Rest of your code...
    // Add this for the script to be sent.
    $("#someEmptyDiv").html(result);
```

------**EDIT**

Okay... You have to possible results:
1- the error message about username already exist
2- A JSON

There is many way to be creative here, depending on what your want to do:

```
$query = mysqli_query($databaseConnection, "SELECT columnTopicTitle FROM tableTopics WHERE columnTopicTitle='".$topicTitle."'");
if (mysqli_num_rows($query) != 0) {
    //echo "Username already exists";
    ?>
    <script>
    $("#myHiddenDiv").html("Username already exists").fadeIn(600);
    </script>
    <?php
} else {
    $advert = array(                 // I assume this works.
        'ajax' => 'Hello world!',
        'advert' => $row['adverts'],
    );
    ?>
    <script>
    close_blue_modal();
    $("#myHiddenDiv").html("Username created").fadeIn(600);
    console.log( " <?php echo json_encode($advert); ?> " );
    </script>
    <?php
    //echo json_encode($advert);
}
```

Then Ajax `success` would be:

```
success: function(result) {
    $("#someEmptyDiv").html(result);
}
```

Comment: Why isn't my javascript working from the php page? It doesn't do anything. I've already tried that...

Comment: It doesn't work *from" the PHP... It is sent by it... Hold on I will add something

Comment: You have to place the ajax result in a `div`. If it is a script, it will execute. Make it hidden... So if it is something else than a script, it will not be shown.

Comment: Okay. Another thing is that in success of my ajax call, I close the box that allows people to submit new topics. But if the topic already exists then I want to keep the box open until a valid topic is entered.

Comment: mmm... Okay... So in clear, you ask Ajax if the username already exist. It looks like you have only 2 possible ansswer 1- the error message 2- Another message... (your Json thing I didn't look at). So in the `success`, you could check it what is the content of the result to make decision

Comment: Oh okay thank you Louys. The error message is working now. But how can I check the content of the result to make a decision?

Comment: I'm just unsure about your resulting JSON... If it is valid and what you plan to do with it. But here is an EDIT to look at.

Comment: You should see your JSON in console... Is it helping a little ?